# What on earth is Grandpa talking about?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa was holding something and looking at it curiously.

"What is that in your hand Grandpa?" I inquired.

"A map son"

> I moved closer. Weird map, I thought. Bunch of planets and sun.
>
> "That can't be right. Mars in between the Sun and Venus?" I was
>   confused.
>
> "Right" said Grandpa
>
> "Hmm. And Neptune next to Venus? No planet between them? And I do not
>   see Earth. No Earth?" I continued.
>
> "Oh there is Earth. There are billions of these maps!"  Grandpa in his
>   calm voice.

What on earth was he talking about? I swear I did not see earth on that map.

Hint

> The map can predict, kind of

Comment: How detailed would you like your answer to be? And is the non-capitalisation of E intensional in the title?

Comment: Nothing intentional. I expect the answer to explain all my curious questions!

Comment: One of the billions of maps published by the Flat Earth Society?

Comment: Once you know the answer you realise that the flavourtext before the block is really clever. I love this - what a great idea, and executed very nicely. You should be very happy with this one DEEM!

Comment: Thanks @Stiv. Appreciate the encouragement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think Grandpa's map, with Mars between the Sun and Venus, and Neptune next to Venus, is a

> Palmistry map of his hand
>
>  [image]
>
>  There are over 15 billion of these 'maps' on Earth - which I can't find either.
>
>  OP points out there are four hand shapes in palmistry - Earth/Air/Water/Fire - the hand was Earth.

Comment: You can say that there are roughly 7.5 billion people on earth, and so approximately 15 billion of your answer?

Comment: @El-Guest, I agree - have the total on the last line. The source is in the answer body - see edit - in case the image looks home-made, and most of other versions I saw had Apollo for the Sun. Still see no Earth, but Grandpa may have been gardening.

Comment: @Tom In Palmistry there are 4 types of hands. Water, fire, wiind and Earth. So the hand itself can be Earth.

Answer (score 11):

These are

> Sky at a Glance maps

Mars between the Sun and Venus. Neptune next to Venus.

> These would be correct at certain times of the year based on the orbital position of the planets.

No Earth.

> These maps are from the perspective of an observer on Earth.

Billions of these maps.

> Not sure about billions, but these maps can be produced for any day/time you want. Astronomy magazines typically include such maps for near sunrise and sunset to help you know what is visible in the sky. Also, you can have a map produced for, say, your child's birthday, as a memento or a gift.

Comment: The number Billions is real @majorbanzai.